# Django assertRedirects test fails due to http://testserver prefix

Tags: django, django-testing, django-1.11

I want to test that `/sitemap.xml/` redirects to `/sitemap.xml`. I'm using this code:

```
res = self.client.get('/sitemap.xml/')
self.assertRedirects(res, '/sitemap.xml', status_code=301)
```

And getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/sitemap.xml', expected '/sitemap.xml'
```

How should I write this test to avoid the `testserver` clash?

Comment: Do you do anything special to initialize `self.client`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the redirect url/response is created with the fullpath using build_absolute_uri or something similar.? Just a guess...

Firstly, using urlnames instead of hardcoded paths may be easier in the long run. url=reverse('sitemap.xml'), url = reverse('sitemap.xml') + '/' to give some idea...

[Django naming url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Anyway this may solve your problem without having to bother about the host.

```
res = self.client.get('/sitemap.xml/')
expected_url = res.wsgi_request.build_absolute_uri('/sitemap.xml')
self.assertRedirects(res, expected_url, status_code=301)
```

(Tested on Django 1.10.6)

Comment: Good guess - that was exactly my problem. Replaced `request.build_absolute_url()` with `request.get_full_path()` in my redirect middleware and it works as expected!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `request.path`

Something like this :

```
response = self.client.get('/sitemap.xml/')
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301)
self.assertEqual(response.path, '/sitemap.xml')
```